# Relationship configuration not deployed to target environment

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

I have made many changes to the cascading configuration of 1:N relationships in the Account entity, everything works as expected in my development environment, but it's not being applied to target environments when deployed.

Here's an example in dev:

[image]

And here's what I find in the target environment:

[image]

I export as unmanaged, and import as unmanaged. I make the changes from within the solution, so obviously, the relationships are included in the solution. Is this a bug in 2016? I think it's the first time ever I try exporting those kind of changes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. In this case, the "Phone Call" entity has to be included in the solution. When adding it to the solution, I "Added all assets".

The cascading is now in effect in the target environment.